# uploading files in email without restriction

Tags: email, upload, restriction

How can I upload a file blocked by email providers?

I want to upload certain programs in my email. but, email provider is blocking it. Any way to workaround this problem?

Comment: Can you quote the **exact** reject message?  One possible reason is that email is too big for this mail server to accept it.

Comment: Actually executable files are rejected by gmail. even if you rename/zip/password protect it can detect that it is executable.

Answer (score 0):

**In linux:**

```
apt install sharutils

uuencode input_filename /dev/stdout > output_filename
```

use pico to remove following first line from <output_filename>

*begin 644 /dev/stdout*

upload in email

when downloaded

use pico to add following line to top of <encoded_filename>

*begin 644 /dev/stdout*

```
uudecode encoded_filename >  decoded_filename
```